# Returning float array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, arrays, memory-management, floating-point

I would like to know how to return float array in methods.

In methods like:

```
- (float *) ......{
    float * result = malloc(sizeof(float) * number);
    ....
    return result;
}
```

My problem is that I didn't clean result float array. How can I do that?

Comment: @iRaviiVooda: that is an quite useless comment. OP asks for a specific — and not trivial — task in Objective-C. Pointing to the top site of that Objective-C documentation is not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem is that i didn't clean result float array.

That's the job of whoever is calling your method that returns the float array: now he owns it, so he must call `free` on it.

Generally, there are two situations:

- **You use the array inside another method or a function without storing it** - In this case, identify the point in your method or a function where the array is no longer needed, and call `free()` passing it the array.
- **You store the array as an instance variable in one of your objects** - In this case, add a `dealloc` method to your class, and call `free()` on the array variable from there.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has methods name convention that describe how you can do that. In your case, you must start your method with `create` prefix and clean allocated memory when no longer need it:

```
float* CreatePointsArray()
{
    float* result = malloc(sizeof(float) * number);
    ....
    return result;
}
...
points = CreatePointsArray();
...
free(points);
```

see more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH)

Will be better put it into standard `NSArray`. But, if you do this, it is better to make function instead of method class.